# Highlighting objects on a web page via Python?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this is possible to do with Python packages, but here we go:

I am making a tool that allows developers to label the different input fields on web pages for an automated testing framework. I have the HTML source of the input, and I would like to display the full web page in a browser and then highlight the input on the page so that the user knows what to look at.

My thought so far is to grab the source of the page, open this in webbrowser, and replace the HTML with the same HTML + "color = green" or whatever, but I was hoping that there was a more elegant / more visually appealing approach.

Comment: JavaScript is the tool for this job, not Python. You will have to find a way to communicate between them.

Comment: While JavaScript may be the best tool, I find it hard to believe that there isn't any way that I can do this with Python.

Comment: Have you looked at templating packages?  E.g.:  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/